# How to make my header in elementor inherit the bg-color of the section it is displayed on

Tags: javascript, css, header, background-color, elementor

I'm currently building a site in elementor for a client and i want the header on my frontpage inherit the bg-color of the section it is displayed on.

i currently have a hero video where the header should be transparent. Further more i the bg-color of the section is changing color with help of this GSAP code snippet:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( jQuery ) {
jQuery(window).on('scroll touchmove', function() {

        if (jQuery(document).scrollTop() \>= jQuery('#one').position().top) {
            jQuery('body').css('background', jQuery('#one').attr('data-color'));
        }
    
        if (jQuery(document).scrollTop() \> jQuery('#two').position().top) {
            jQuery('body').css('background', jQuery('#two').attr('data-color'));
    });\`\`

})(jQuery);
```

Therefor my header needs to go from transparent -> #002C50 -> #21654E

initially i thought it could be done with setting the "inherit property" but it does't seem to work.

Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: So you want the header to have the same background as the body? `jQuery('body, header').css(...)`

Comment: Yes! So when the body are blue the header should match and when the body turns green the header should also match :)